# How do I update memcache php extension

Tags: php, memcached

Following Ubuntu update to 22.04 PHP is now on 8.1.

Looks like the php-memcache extension therefore needs updated to 3.2.0 per: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/19149

Not that knowledgable about pear/pecl PHP package repositories and commands, so not making much progress in getting this updated, does anyone have the steps I might be able to follow?

```
$ pecl download memcached
$ tar zxvf memcached-1.0.0.tgz (or whatever version downloads)
$ cd memcached-1.0.0
$ phpize
$ ./configure --with-libmemcached-dir=/opt/local
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

The above is failing on ./configure --with-libmemcached-dir=/opt/local

```
checking for libmemcached location... configure: error: memcached support requires libmemcached. Use --with-libmemcached-dir=<DIR> to specify the prefix where libmemcached headers and library are located
```

Comment: If you've installed php with apt, you can install php-memcached the same way.

Comment: Make sure you have the libmemcached development package installed on your system.

`sudo apt install libmemcached-dev`

Comment: Thanks Mohammed, yes got that installed and got it working eventually. 
For future info I used aptitude to install libmemcached-dev and had to choose the second solution to get it working (downgrade packages - this is on ubuntu 22.04)


     Downgrade the following packages:
1)     libmemcached11 [1.0.18-5+deb.sury.org~xenial+2 (now) -> 1.0.18-4.2ubuntu4 (jammy)]
2)     libmemcachedutil2 [1.0.18-5+deb.sury.org~xenial+2 (now) -> 1.0.18-4.2ubuntu4 (jammy)

Also changed ./configure command as above to "./configure --with-libmemcached-dir=/usr --disable-memcached-sasl".

Comment: Please also note, memcache !== memcached